# How to paste some text in Sublime?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, sublimetext4

I need to paste `console.log()` very often. I want to create a hotkey for this. And the cursor should be between brackets (usual pasting doesn't work so).
How to do this? It doesn't look like this can be configured in the settings. Maybe some plugin. I'd rather create a little script for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No plugins are needed; you just need to create a new [snippet](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/completions.html#snippets). Select **`Tools → Developer → New Snippet…`** and the following will appear:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
Hello, ${1:this} is a ${2:snippet}.
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <!-- <tabTrigger>hello</tabTrigger> -->
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

First, replace the contents of the `CDATA` designator in the `<content>` tag with `console.log($0)`. The `$0` is a [field designator](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/completions.html#fields). Snippets also support a number of built-in [variables](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/completions.html#variables).

Next, set a trigger sequence - something that when you type it and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the snippet will be triggered. `clog` should work.

Next, you can set a [scope selector](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/selectors.html) to refine the context in which the snippet can be triggered. If nothing is in this field, the snippet will be available everywhere. Assuming you're programming in JavaScript, use `source.js` here.

Finally, we'll add a `<description>` field that will show up in the autocomplete popup. Otherwise, it'll just show `clog` as the description. Here, we'll use `console.log()`.

Here's what the final snippet will look like:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
console.log($0)
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>clog</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.js</scope>
    <description>console.log()</description>
</snippet>
```

Hit Save and the save dialog will come up in your `Packages/User` folder*. Save the snippet here (otherwise it may not work) as `clog.sublime-snippet`. Once saved, it is immediately activated. You can test it by switching to a JS file and typing `clog` and hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd>. `console.log()` should be entered at that position, with the cursor between the parentheses.

---

* The exact path of the `Packages` directory depends on your operating system and whether or not you've upgraded your installation to Sublime Text 4 (Build 4000 and greater).

- Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages` or `~/.config/sublime-text/Packages`
- macOS/OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages` or `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text/Packages`
- Windows Regular Install: `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages` or `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text\Packages`
- Windows Portable Install: `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages` or `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text\Data\Packages`

Comment: This helped to do what I wanted: https://superuser.com/questions/1001191/sublime-paste-in-snippet

Comment: I need only `<content>` to paste with a hotkey (not a keyword).